# How to make a glowing picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

From [How to make a glowing text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545901/how-to-make-a-glowing-text)

Is there a way to do it also on pictures ?

To show the wanted effect, an example is provided with a screenshot from Word, I can insert a picture, say a PNG with alpha layer, right click, Format Picture..., Effects (pentagon), Glow (presets), it will follow the contour of the picture (orange, bottom) not just create a rectangle around it (green, top).

[image: microsoft_word_picture_glow]

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE. Your question doesn't appear to be related to this website. You may consider asking it at some other StackExchange website.

Comment: *Edit* Seeing your tags, it seems you want to do it with LaTeX. You may consider updating your question to reflect that.

Comment: I cannot add the tag, it refused me to do it because not enough "reputation". Yet we're in the Tex part of stackexchange, so I guess I'm not really offside.

Comment: LaTeX is automatically assumed here unless otherwise specified, so [tag:latex] is 'banned'. But the point is the question doesn't seem to have any particular LaTeX link; you'd likely be best to draw this in another tool.

Comment: Well, not necessarily, as I want as much as possible done natively in LaTeX and not relying on external program people might not own. Do a MWE that request Photoshop... Anyway, I was inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244650/glowing-path-in-tikz and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567286/pdfstringdef-turns-accented-characters-into-octal-escape-sequence/ with a ton of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193555/crop-jpeg-into-circular-tikz-node

Comment: Oh, and btw, as stated in a linked question ('pdfstringdef') : I cannot add the tags 'latex', or 'glow' or 'pdfstringdef' unless I have 300 "reputation". "Yeah, that'd be great..." So it's not out of boredom that many tags are missing, just that this place seems rather unfriendly to newcomers and doesn't allows them to do so.

Comment: Could you provide a MWE? At least create a document and insert the picture so people can help you improve your code to get the glowing effect. PS: you cannot create new tags yet, but there are already a lot of existing tags. The objective is too avoid too many tags, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/tagging for more information.

Comment: @Kochise This is one of the most welcoming communities I've ever come across (here or elsewhere). Don't be misled by the "abruptness" of comments, tone can be hard to convey. The tag `latex` is a bit redundant as 99% of the questions are about that. The tags you have used are fine, I think. The effect you're looking might not be impossible with TikZ but it might require some time for someone to post it, yours is not an easy question, which is why somebody advised you to use other tools, not because we don't want to help, I would, but rather to be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks, as I improved a text version (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567286/pdfstringdef-turns-accented-characters-into-octal-escape-sequence/ to get an idea) I hoped something like 'contour' can also achieve something similar on vector/raster image. I bet the solution is not that difficult, perhaps... I'll dive into it later, but sure, I'll try to provide a MWE :)